# Download PDF in Chrome from TCPDF

Tags: php, pdf, google-chrome, tcpdf

When a downloading PDF file in Chrome 12.0.742.91 (either as an attachment and inline), the download is interrupted (at the beginning it shows 125KB, but later 127518/0 B and then it stops entirely).

The file download works correctly in Firefox and IE. Headers are correct, apache returns `200 OK`.
Previously, everything was ok, probably until a Chrome update a few days ago.

Comment: just checked in chrome may re-installation solve this

Comment: can i try error in my browser?

Comment: https://fakturex.pl/tcpdf-test

Comment: have u checked the normal/blank pdf page download in chrome if it works need to troubleshoot content in page

Comment: It does not matter what is in the content, does not work for several sites, with different templates etc.

Comment: @dominik The problem could be related to the transparent gzip. Can you disable gzipping the PDF and try it again? If that works, please write an answer to your question here and file a chromium bug report.

Comment: It works! I changed ob_start('ob_gzhandler') to ob_start(). I can not answer to own question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just for further reference: The problem is related to the gzip handling. Disabling transparent gzip compression solved it.

Comment: How do you disable transparent gzip compression?

Comment: It depends on your webserver. Just use the [stackoverflow search](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=disable+gzip)

Comment: Disabling transparent gzip compression might have been a temporary solution, and thanks for pointing it out. However, is this issue in the pipeline for fixes on Chrome or should we be suggesting users to use other browsers if compressed content is a deal breaker?

Answer (score 1):

Check your Content-Length header. It seems to be returning a size smaller than the file itself. I suspect Chrome is interrupting the download as its receiving more bytes than it should. It would be easy to put a test case in place for this however.

Comment: I saw your comment now. It still may be related to the content-size. But with no gzip its no longer a problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had problems when the name of the file served contained weird characters like some accents (á é í ó ú) or this degree symbol: º.